# WordPress rewrite does not work for some reason

Tags: rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I am learning how to use [WordPress rewrites](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule). As a start i am just trying to redirect any request for "**validate_data.php**" to "**validate-data**". Here is what i have added to the functions.php file:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule( 'validate_data.php', 'validate-data', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_basic' );
```

I know i can execute this in the .htaccess file, but i am testing it here as i have a more advanced case, so it is just a start. What happens when i access "validate_data.php" is that it causes 404 error. I hope someone can tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to WordPress rewrites, so after some StackExchange reading i have figured it out. All rewrites should be passed to index.php, then i can call the page that i want to redirect to, like this:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'validate_data.php', 'index.php?pagename=validate-data', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_basic' );
```

In addition i wanted to pass some POST data from the old page to the new page, so i did it like this:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^validate_data.php(.+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=validate-data', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_basic' );
```

Hope that helps new starters like me some day :)